# Modelling a robot using urdf / xacro for Moveit

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there
I'm working with a robot in Moveit: [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/staubli) you can find the package of the robot.

I have an issue with their articulations, as it's shown in those pictures:

1-
All joints are in their initial position:

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

2-After moving Joint_2 in Moveit, this is what happen:

[image: image description]

This first link_1 get out from the robot !!

My question as you probably understand, is how and where can I fix that issue :D ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197752/modelling-a-robot-using-urdf-/-xacro-for-moveit/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-19**:
As the author of the [staubli](http://wiki.ros.org/staubli) packages in the repository you link, I'm quite sure that the model you show in your screenshot is *not* part of that repository. You should probably clarify that in your question.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-19**:
Yes gvdhoorn You're right.
I was thinking about that when writing the question but I figure that it'll complicate the question !!
So as you are the author; where the center rotation is defined or how can I solve that problem ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-19**:
Also: this is not really MoveIt related, but is a simple matter of modelling your robot correctly using urdf / xacro. I'd suggest updating your question title (and tags) to reflect this.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-20**:
I changed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would appear to be an incorrectly specified center of rotation (origin) for the joint between `link_1` and `link_2`, judging from the screenshot. Are you sure you defined their locations (and orientations) correctly?

---

Edit:

> when I delete all directories and files except rx160.urdf and meshes; it still wokring ! How can you explain that !

If by 'is still working' you mean you can still visualise the model, then that is not really hard to explain: all you need for that *are* the urdf and the meshes. All the other files in the package are just for documentation, packaging and convenience (the `test_rx160.launch` file fi).

> and in the urdf we can't do lot of things !

I don't really understand what you're trying to say.

The urdf is just a textual description of the kinematic structure of your robot. In the case of the `staubli_rx160_support` package, this is based on the dimensions of the physical RX 160 from Stäubli.

All you need to do is update the urdf with the information for your particular robot model, and make sure you create some meshes that match it. As Stäubli provides 3D models of their manipulators on their website, this should not be too difficult (but watch the origins and orientations of your links).

If you are not familiar with urdf, you might want to take a look at [urdf/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials). If you are, perhaps [Create a URDF for an Industrial Robot](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create%20a%20URDF%20for%20an%20Industrial%20Robot) could provide you some more insight into how that knowledge was used to create the `staubli_rx160_support` package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-19**:
What I'm doing actually is that I'm using a package for Robot_1 with Robot_2 (mine). this is why I get that Error..
I'm looking for where can I get those parameters that you're taking about :D

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-19**:
So you are using the urdf of the RX160, with your own meshes? No, that will not work (most of the time).

There are multiple ways to get details on the kinematic structure: the Staubli Studio can show them, or you can use the *General Description* section of the *Instruction Manual*.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-19**:
Yes exactly that's what I'm doing !
I have 3D model of my robot working in Staubli studio so I have all details about it.
But how can I use or edit your package !?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-19**:
You could use the RX160 urdf as a template, but update the joint transforms with the data for your particular model. Be sure to update the axis definitions as well, otherwise it won't work. The studio should have a textbox somewhere it can show the DH params, which you can use to update the urdf.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-19**:
it not really clear where should I go.. but I'll look at that :D
Thank you so much :D

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-19**:
First create a copy of the RX160 pkg, and name it after your own model. Then start updating all file-, urdf, launch file and xacro names to match your own model. Now update the urdf with the proper lengths of links and the joint limits of your model. You should end up with a pkg just for your robot.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-19**:
oh that's more clear, I can't thank you enough :D

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-20**:
@Gvdhoorn
I worked little bit today on your package but I don't really get any new results, I wanna ask you:
when I delete all directories and files except rx160.urdf and meshes; it still wokring !
How can you explain that !
and in the urdf we can't do lot of things !

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-20**:
First when I said it working I mean the articulations in Moveit: we can change different joins only using urdf+meshes !!?
=> how it still working or how it works ?

I didn't work with urdf before but it was easy for me to understand what is written in it (what each join or link structure is for etc)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-20**:
You keep saying MoveIt, but I think you mean the [joint_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher). Are you using `test_rx160.launch`? And yes, there is no magic: RViz is just a visualisation tool. If you change joint states, it will update its visualisation.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-20**:
No I'm working with Moveit and I do all with it:
[http://i.imgur.com/b7EF9a0.png](https://i.imgur.com/b7EF9a0.png)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-20**:
Well I don't know what else to tell you: the problem you are seeing is because your urdf is incorrect: the location and orientation of your joints is wrong, or you have specified the wrong `axis`. I advise you to get some more experience with urdfs, and then just try again.